# SwiftUI tap on image to select an area - better way than this?

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, uiimage

Updating an app I did for a car club that connects their customers (dealerships, parties, firehouse events, town events, tv commercials, magazine ads, etc) with their members to rent out fancy/classic/muscle cars for photo ops and eye-candy at events. The car owner gets paid, the car club takes a small percentage for club costs and events. It handles CRM stuff, scheduling, photos, etc.

The new feature they want is a way to quickly look over a car before and after an event, tap an area on the screen and describe any damages (plus other functions). They want to be able to look up stuff over time and do comparisons, etc., perhaps generate repair invoices, etc.

I have come up with a basic formula that works: image of the car is displayed, a transparent mask image above it in the z-order, masked with different colors. The user taps, I look up the color at the tap event, draw a circle on the image, use that color as an index into part or region list, record all the info, and bob's your uncle.

This just shortcuts having a bunch of drop downs or selectors or whatever to manually pick a part or region from a list, and give is some visual sugar.

Works, works nicely, and is consistently reliable (images are PNG - colors get munched up too much in JPG compression). This works great. It all falls apart if they decide they want to change images; they want me to retroactively draw circles on the new images based on old records' information. My firm line so far has been "no, you can't do that", because the tap locations are tied to the original images. They're insistent on trying, so...

I have two questions.

First is simple - am I missing something painfully obvious as a better way to do this? (select a known value for a section of a graphic)?

Second one is - loading stock images into the asset catalog, displaying them from 1x images, finding the scale value and adjusting tap locations, etc., all works great. At 2x and 3x, the scaling gets wonky. Loading from storage is the bigger issue... it seems when I load a pair image files from storage, turn it into a Data object, then shove that into a UIImage for display in a SwiftUI Image View, I lose the easy scaling from when I embed images in the assets catalog under the 1x slot. Is there a way to load the file->Data->UIImage->Image( uiImage: xxx ) and force a 1x rendering, skipping any auto-rendering/scaling that iOS might do?

Thoughts?

Below are quickly masked sample images I'm using to display the car and mask, each green area is slightly different in the RGB's G value, and I just use that as the lookup key for the part name in the description ("Front left fender", "Rocker panel", "Left rear wheel", "Windshield", and so forth).

[image: Mask overlaying image, then made transparent]

[image: The image the user sees]

Comment: There is software that Law Enforcement uses to handle car crashes. Their software effectively does the same thing for reporting. Perhaps looking into that might give you some valuable research that might help. I know that there were several "Templates" that were effectively sides of the car from 5 different angles (Front, Back, Left, Right, and Top), for each individual vehicle type (Truck, Car, Suv, Tractor, Bus, etc..) and they were generic enough to fit anything.

Comment: have you been recording the specific tap locations in coordinates, or just the underlying part derived from the mask? And if they now want to change the pictures, the masks won't fit anymore either?

Comment: @ChrisR I'm currently recording the coordinates, yeah. I can draw the circles on the existing parts at will, and at any scale. Changing the picture would necessitate changing the mask, too; So far we're looking at offering that as an upsell to offset that work until (if) we can just add a mask-maker to the app or something. It's a complicated problem added to a simple app :) We're basically holding firm on "no, can't do that", and just going with stock photos by car type, maybe in a line-art manner like cops and insurance companies use. #exploringoptions Thanks!

Comment: PS... the image (and mask) gets a UUID with it, and is included in the tap->save with screen coordinates for history, and the images are kept (essentially forever) for history. I think that'll do. And we'll just not allow changing images for the time being.

Comment: yes, I don't even understand why they would want to change images retrospectively ...?

Comment: Honestly, I think it's one of those things like when you show the kid the candy, the kid wants the candy. Someone (not me) mentioned being able to change your pictures, and whammo... people who don't understand the tech started making a wish list. I think I have them reined in on it. (he said, hoping)